# Not allow duplicates in google spreadsheet

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google spreadsheet like database table and would like first field be unique. How to check field unique before update. Or maybe I can somehow set column A not allow not unique fields?

I'm using C# to work with spreadsheet:

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string spreadsheetId = "1IAD2okAWZD7anbt5L4ybgD2dxHBGmsY6IkNIWHBQkBM";
        string ApplicationName = "sheets";
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials_1.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });




        String range = "new first sheet!A1"; // mano
        //var range = "{sheet}!D543";
        var valueRange = new ValueRange();

        var oblist = new List<object>() { "aaa","bbb","ccc" };
        valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { oblist };

        var updateRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range);

        updateRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
        var appendReponse = updateRequest.Execute();

    }
```

Comment: "How to check unique before update."  Your question needs clarification.  Are you asking how to add a field and make sure that field doesn't exist already?  Or are you trying to update a field of a record and want to make sure your updated value is unique for the entire record set? Or some other scenario???

Comment: I need to update table with record. Column `A` in this table should be unique. I would like spreadsheet to check unique before update. If that not possible what is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Use data validation with error on invalid entry, it use your own program to analyze the existing values in accordance with your own requirements

Comment: But for this reason I should fetch all records in table into my program. And I would like server to make check unique job.

Comment: What is the intended behavior that should occur if you try to update a record and the value you insert is not unique?  Should the update fail?  Should the value be dropped from the record?  Something else?

Comment: If not unique - fail update.

Comment: From what I see, there a procedures for uniqueness that operate on existing records, but I don't think there is a way to make an update that fails on not unique.  I think you will have to do what tehhowch said.